# LINQ to Entities: pattern for null parent

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm querying an Entity Framework model, so In this case, I'm using LINQ to Entities. It just means I can't use all of the latest operators.

Here's a LINQ select statement:

```
            var nodes = r.Find(pn =>
                pn.StatusId == PageStatus.Active &&
                pn.IncludeInSitemap &&
                sitemap.Contains(pn.PageTemplate.SiteSectionId))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.PageTemplate.RouteName,
                    x.RouteValues,
                    x.PageTemplate.PhysicalFile,
                    MetaLastModified = x.PageMeta.LastModified,
                    ContentBlock = x.PageContent != null
                        ? x.PageContent.ContentBlock
                        : default,
                    ContentLastModified = x.PageContent != null
                        ? x.PageContent.LastModified
                        : default,
                    x.PageType.Priority
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority)
                .ThenBy(x => x.RouteName)
                .ToList();
```

As you can see, I have two properties where I need to check PageContent is not null. I can't make use of the "?" operator because it is LINQ to Entities. However, I wondered if it is possible to do the NULL check on the parent once (instead of the two) and set both properties accordingly.

LINQ is a bit alien to me, so it could be a very simple answer or impossible.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the number of columns the datasource(s) have you could always materialize the data in memory and perform non-linq to entities functions by adding a `.AsEnumerable()` before the operations.

Comment: what is the error message you got?

Comment: Not recommendable when you have either a lot of columns or large amounts of data per row

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: I'm aware of the pitfalls of AsEnumerable(), but I wouldn't sacrifice performance for the sake of a few lines of (ugly) code. I was really looking to see if there was a neater way of doing what I'm already doing that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score -1):

something like this  ?

```
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.PageTemplate.RouteName,
                    x.RouteValues,
                    x.PageTemplate.PhysicalFile,
                    MetaLastModified = x.PageMeta.LastModified,
                    PageContent = x.PageContent
                    x.PageType.Priority
                })
             .Select(anonymousClass => 
                         anonymousClass.PageContent is PageContentType pg ? 
                                  new { ... } : 
                                  new {})
```

if we replace the anonymous class by a real class... then the constructor can have the one time test you want to assure the deduced properties are correctly set...

Comment: can you please explain why this deserved a  or other negative votes ??